# Continuity of $\cos(x), \sin(x)$ and $\exp(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

If we wish to prove that $\cos(x), \sin(x)$ and $\exp(x)$ are continuous, can we shorten the argument by saying that each one of them has a power series and all polynomials are continuous, provided that the latter statement is already proven. Would that be sufficient to prove the continuity of these functions or is it too naive to think so?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: No, that's not enough, since a power series is not a polynomial. You also need results on which kind of convergence those power series have.

Comment: $ f_{n}(x)=x^{n}$ for $x \in [0,1]$ converges as $n \to \infty$  to a function that is not continuous

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, power series are continuous inside their convergence radius. What you need is that the power series converges locally uniformly and that the uniform limit of a sequence of continuous functions is continuous again. However, if you only want to prove that $\sin$, $\cos$ and $\exp$ are continuous, you are probably quicker with a direct proof.

Answer (score 0):

you can also prove that they are continuous using the definition:
For instance, prove that the function $f(x)=sin(x)$ is continuous at $a \in dom(f)$:

Let $\epsilon>0$  there's $\delta>0$ such that $|x-a|<\delta$ then $|sin(x)-sin(a)|<\epsilon$:

If $|sin(x)-sin(a)|=|2sin(\frac{x-a}{2})cos(\frac{x+a}{2})|\leq|2(\frac{x-a}{2})|=|x-a|<\delta$

if we choose $\delta=\epsilon$ sucht that $|x-a|<\delta \Rightarrow |sin(x)-sin(a)|<\epsilon$.

therefore $f$ is continuous in a.